# Sequence of matrices with bounded/unbounded image

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in the following context

Let

1. $\{S_1, S_2 \dots S_n\}$ a set of $n$ invertible matrices of dimension $n \times n$.
2. for every positive interger $m$, $p_m := \cfrac{1-(-\alpha)^m}{1 + \alpha}$ and $q_m := \cfrac{\alpha+(-\alpha)^m}{1 + \alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is fixed in the open interval $(0,1)$.

For every positive integer $m$, and for any $i \in [1..n]$, the matrices $S_i$ must verify the following:

1. $S_i^m = p_m\cdot S_i + q_m\cdot I$.
2. $\| S^m_i \|_1 = 1 + p_m$

Now, take the vector $e_1=(1,0,0\dots 0)$ (or any vector of the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$) and consider this set of vectors:

$$\{ S^{m_1}_{i_1}\cdot S^{m_2}_{i_2}\dots S^{m_r}_{i_r}\cdot e_1 , \ r \ge 1, i_j \in [1..n],\  m_i \in \mathbb Z^+ \}$$

I have good numerical reasons to think that this set is unbounded for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$, but I cannot manage to prove it. Note that for $\alpha = 1$ this set is bounded. Any clue or idea will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for comment. The fact is that you have no bound on the number of $S_i^{m_i}$ you can apply and then maybe applying a sufficient long string $S^{m_{i_1}}_{i_1}\cdot S^{m_{i_2}}_{i_2} \dots S^{m_{i_r}}_{i_r}$ we can grow the norm indefinitely.

Comment: Yes interesting but your $S_1$ and $S_2$ do not satisfy the condition $\| S^m_i \|_1 = 1 + p_m, \ \forall i =1\dots n$.

Comment: Yes , very sorry you are right, I have rephrased the problem

Comment: Would you please exhibit an example of a matrix $S_i$ that satisfies your two conditions?

Comment: There are many operator norms, and the symbolism for them sometimes varies. Can you give the definition you are using for $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: Take a graph on $n$ vertices and let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of that graph. Define $S_i$ as the identity matrix except that the $ith$ row of $S_i$ is the row of $A$ and $(S_i)_{ii} = -\alpha$.

$$
\|S\|_1 := \max\limits_{i} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}|s_{ij}|
$$

Comment: Thank you. FYI - notifications for comments are sent to someone only if (1) the comment is to a post by that person (thus I was notified of your comment on my now-deleted answer. (2) the comment is on any post within a thread started by that person (thus you will be notified of all comments on any answers here), or (3) you specifically address the comment to that person by typing "@" followed by their username (without internal spaces). Thus I can include @user1551 to notifiy user1551 that you also answered their question in your previous comment.  Alas, you can only so address one person.

Answer (score 1):

This is not always true. The easiest counterexample is to take a family of commuting diagonalisable $S_i$s, such as $S_1=\cdots=S_n$. Since the only possible eigenvalues of each $S_i$ are $1$ or $-\alpha$, if all $S_i$s can be simultaneously diagonalised by some change-of-basis matrix $P$, then the product of the powers of the $S_i$s must be in the form of $PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are nonnegative integer powers of $-\alpha$. It follows that the product is bounded above in norm.

For a less obvious counterexample, suppose $n\ge3$. For each $i<n$,  let $S_i$ be obtained by modifying the $i$-row of the identity matrix to
$$
(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{i-1\text{ copies}},-\alpha,1,\ldots,1).
$$
Let also $S_n$ be obtained by removing one of the $1$s on the top row or $S_1$. These $S_i$s do not commute with each other, but your two conditions are satisfied. Now let $\beta$ be the positive real number such that $\alpha+\beta+\beta^2+\ldots+\beta^{n-1}=1$. Let also $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,\beta,\beta^2,\ldots,\beta^{n-1})$ and $M_i=D^{-1}S_iD$ for each $i$. That is, for each $i<n$, $M_i$ is obtained by modifying the $i$-row of the identity matrix to
$$
(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{i-1\text{ copies}},-\alpha,\beta,\beta^2,\ldots,\beta^{n-i}),
$$
and $M_n$ is obtained by removing a nonzero off-diagonal entry from the top row of $M_1$. Then $\|M_i\|_\infty=1$ for every $i$. Therefore, for any vector $x$ with $\|x\|_\infty\le1$, we have
\begin{aligned}
\|S_{i_1}^{m_1}\cdots S_{i_r}^{m_r}x\|_\infty
&=\|DM_{i_1}^{m_1}\cdots M_{i_r}^{m_r}D^{-1}x\|_\infty\\
&\le\|D\|_\infty\|M_{i_1}\|_\infty^{m_1}\cdots \|M_{i_r}\|_\infty^{m_r}\|D^{-1}\|_\infty\|x\|_\infty\\
&\le\|D\|_\infty\|D^{-1}\|_\infty\\
&=\beta^{1-n}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the usual definition of the infinity norm is  $\|A\|_{\infty} := \max\limits_{i} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$ and then I suppose you want to write $\|M\|_{\infty} \le 1$ and not $\|M\|_{\infty} = 1$.

In your second very interesting example, the relation $S_i^m = p_m\cdot S_i + q_m$ has not uniform $p_m$ and $q_m$ valid for any $S_i$ (but I didn't specify that). Thanks again for this example it give me ideas on how to manage the case (interesting for me) when the $S_i$ are build based on the adjacency matrice of a graph.